# lambda calculus type assigned problem

Tags: lambda-calculus

we have $\lambda xabc.xa(xbc)$ and we should give a type for it
can we assign $a$ and $b$ to the same symbol ? like
here $a$ and $b$ should be same type for example $\alpha$ so we can continue ?
$a,b = \alpha$
$c=\beta$
$x = \alpha \rightarrow \beta \rightarrow \beta$
is it correct this way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are saying, but from context it seems like you are asking what the type of $\lambda x a b c.x~a~(x~b~c)$ should be, and in particular, if we can show
$a, b : \alpha$, $c : \beta$, and $x : \alpha \to \beta \to \beta$. You are correct, and I'll explain in detail how we can figure this out:

We have a term $\lambda x a b c . x ~ a ~(x~b~c)$. Let's start by saying $a : \alpha$,
$b : \beta$, $c : \gamma$, $x:\chi$. Let's see if we can figure out constraints on our types in order to make the above term well-typed.

The first thing to notice is that $x$ is a function of 2 arguments. If we look at 
$x~b~c$, we know that $x : \beta \to \gamma \to \tau$. This is because $b : \beta$ and $c : \gamma$, but we cannot constrain our output type (yet).

Now we see we *also* need $x~a~(x~b~c)$ to be well typed. So $a$ must have type $\beta$ (since that is the type of $x$'s first argument) and $(x~b~c)$ must have type $\gamma$ (since that is the type of $x$'s second argument).

So now we have also constrained the output type of $x$. We must have $x : \beta \to \gamma \to \gamma$, and this is where we can stop.

$a,b : \beta$, $c : \gamma$, and $x : \beta \to \gamma \to \gamma$ is consistent with our constraints, and there is no extra information to use. Of course, we can clean this up a little bit (renaming our type variables to be closer to the front of the alphabet) and write the final answer (which you correctly gave):

$a,b : \alpha$, $c : \beta$, and $x : \alpha \to \beta \to \beta$.

Keep in mind that this $\alpha$ is different from the $\alpha$ we were using before! We have renamed everything in sight, and I've known some students who get confused by this step.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: sorry because i didn't fom the question correctly maybe, yes the answer helped because the main thing that i'm asking about is that can a and b have the same type other wise we can't give type to this term

Comment: Oooooh, I understand now! Thanks for the clarification ^_^ yes, a and b are allowed to have the same type. You're completely correct in thinking that they NEED to have the same type if $\lambda xabc.xa(xbc)$ is well typed.

Comment: another question is how to deal with the free variables in the lambda term term?
fro example :  λzt.za(bt) we have a and b are free variables and also needs to be same type here too ?is it correct ?

Comment: Not quite! In that term, we don't know anything about a, but we know b is a function! So a and b _might_ be the same, but they don't _need_ to be

Comment: @MustafaAzzurri - If the answer is satisfactory, it would be better to accept it.

Comment: yes sure .. all thanks @HallaSurvivor for the answers

Comment: @MustafaAzzurri - Please, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) how you can accept an answer to you question.